# Connecting SQLite with PHP code

Tags: php, sqlite

I created a database with one table using SQLite. However, I am trying to get the data using PHP code but it doesn't work. Any help?

My code:

```
if ($pdo == null) {
    $pdo = new PDO('sqlite:/db/attendance');
}

$result = $myPDO->query("SELECT * from Student");
```

[image]

Comment: You don't say anything about the version of PHP you're using, but it might not support it. Read up here: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.php

Comment: I am using php 5.6, the SQLiteconnection connects successfully to the DB but I can run it from the php code

Comment: What does a `var_dump($result)` give you?

Comment: Actually, there is not result as the line gives an error:
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file' in /Attendance/index.php:16 Stack trace: #0 /Attendance/index.php(16): PDO->__construct('sqlite:/db/atte...') #1 {main} thrown in /Attendance/index.php on line 16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you ask PHP to open `/db/attendance` you are specifying an *absolute path*: a file called `attendance` in a directory called `db` in the root of your filesystem.

You probably want to specify either a relative path, or an absolute path that is built from your script's location.

Try leaving the leading `/` off of the front of your path:

```
$pdo = new PDO('sqlite:db/attendance');
```

or, even better, building it from [the `__DIR__` magic constant](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php):

```
$pdo = new PDO('sqlite:' . __DIR__ . '/db/attendance');
```